# python rose plot - can't return the figure

Tags: python, return

ok so I have been using this package to create some nice roseplots:

https://bitbucket.org/topper/roseplot

and it is working well.

My first issue however is that I can't change the path where the plot is saved. In the roseplot.py script I found a line that says

```
 plt.savefig(plotname, dpi=300)
```

But even if I change that to

```
plt.savefig('C:\\...\\%s'%plotname, dpi=300)
```

It still saves the .png in the same directory as before.

But my main issue is actually that I would like to use `return` so that I can write a function that returns the roseplot. Then I could for example include the rospeplot in a pdf file.

e.g. like this:

```
def wave_rose():
    data=np.array(data)
    theta=np.array(direction_data)
    fig=Rose(data,theta,"label",title="title")
    return fig

with PdfPages('C:\\...\\figures.pdf') as pdf:    
    pdf.savefig(wave_rose())
```

Anybody has any idea on how to do that?

Comment: What behaviour do you observe and which behaviour did you expect? `savefig` in the source is called with `plotname` being a filename, while `Rose` is a class (so you return a class instance instead of a file name).

Comment: Its two different things that i want. First I want to change the path where the file is saved. The second thing is, that I would somehow like to return the plot. I don't know how I would have to modify the source file or how I would have to call the Class in order to achieve that.